# Retain count exhausted after @throw

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, sentestingkit

When I run this code inside a call made from SenTest's `STAssertThrowsSpecificNamed`:

```
@throw [[NSException alloc] initWithName:NSInvalidArchiveOperationException
                                  reason:@"---some reason----"
                               userInfo:nil];
```

I get (with `NSZombieEnabled=YES`):

```
*** -[NSException reason]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x100a81d60
```

The exception is somehow deallocated before `STAssertThrowsSpecificNamed` has finished processing it.

I can avoid the error by replacing the `@throw` line above with this code:

```
NSException *exception = [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInvalidArchiveOperationException
                                                 reason:@"---some reason----"
                                               userInfo:nil];
@throw exception;
```

I get exactly the same behavior with or without ARC. Without ARC this code avoids the error too:

```
@throw [[[NSException alloc] initWithName:NSInvalidArchiveOperationException
                                   reason:@"---some reason----"
                                userInfo:nil] retain];
```

Is this a bug in SenTest? Or a bug in the compiler? Or is my first `@throw` just incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm now exclusively using `+[NSException raise:format:]` under both ARC and manual retain–release.

Answer (score 2):

@throw releases the object after it's done using it, so use -retain if you want to include it on the same line as @throw.

```
@throw [[[[NSException alloc] initWithName:NSInvalidArchiveOperationException
                                  reason:@"---some reason----"
                               userInfo:nil] retain] autorelease];
```

This should do the trick.

EDIT: To check for ARC-specific code, use:

```
if(__has_feature(objc_arc)) {
    @throw [[[NSException alloc] initWithName:NSInvalidArchiveOperationException
                                       reason:@"---some reason----"
                                     userInfo:nil];
} else {
    @throw [[[[NSException alloc] initWithName:NSInvalidArchiveOperationException
                                      reason:@"---some reason----"
                                   userInfo:nil] retain] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: And is the second example what you recommend under ARC, where I can't use `retain`?

Comment: The reason this would work is because I see that @throw releases the NSExceptions you create, so if you pass a -retain/-autorelease NSException to it, it will retain, and release when necessary. Retain counts are supposed to be used this way when "giving an object to another object", and with -autorelease, it just means "released if necessary, or leave it the garbage collection".

Comment: Under ARC, you might have to define it as __strong (if I remember correctly, since I try hard to avoid ARC). In ARC, retain counts are indirectly handled by the modern runtime, and weak and strong typing tells it what to do with the object.

Comment: I need a solution that works for each, so for now I'm using the second code block from my original post: `id exc = [NSException exceptionWithName:....]; @throw exc;`.

Comment: It still strikes me as odd that `@throw` is intentionally designed this way.

Comment: You need to change `if(__has_feature...` to `#if __has_feature(` for the above code to compile under ARC, but it still doesn't work (see original post).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sticking with this form, for now, which seems to work, both **with and without ARC**.

```
id exc = [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInvalidArchiveOperationException
                                 reason:@"---some reason----"
                               userInfo:nil];
@throw exc;
```

Per Galaxas0's answer, `@throw` is designed to release the exception after it processes it. This still strikes me as odd, especially under ARC.

In a non-ARC project, use this (also per Galaxas0):

```
@throw [[[[NSException alloc] initWithName:NSInvalidArchiveOperationException
                                    reason:@"---some reason----"
                                  userInfo:nil] retain] autorelease];
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `+raise:format:` in NSException instead? I have had no memory issues using that pattern.

Comment: I think that's what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure completely, but that's how I *believe* it's designed. Apple suggests the use of the first statement. If my answer (or yours) was helpful, please mark it as the correct answer! :]

Comment: @Galaxas0, it was partially helpful; I upvoted it. See my comments there.

Comment: Thanks then! I'll up vote this post since it's a complement to my post.